# Client-side encryption in Postgresql with Android app

Tags: php, android, postgresql, encryption

I have read that I can do client-side encryption in Postgresql. I have an Android app that connects via https to an Apache web server that has a php script that connects to the database (for the time being MySQL free edition but I can migrate to Postgresql). How should I see the client-side encryption in this story? Which steps should I take? The database must be free (school project).

Answer (score -2):

You must set up the PostgreSQL server to support SSL. See [the documentation in the Chapter “Server Setup and Operation”](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssl-tcp.html#SSL-SERVER-FILES).

Then use `sslmode = require` in your PostgreSQL connection string.